# geode: "create region" is not available. Reason: Requires connection

Tags: geode

I've followed the instructions on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutes an started a locator and a server. When I try to create a region, I get an error message: "*"create region" is not available. Reason: Requires connection.*".

Could you please help me with a solution ?

I'm running my locator, my server and the region in 3 separate windows.

- OS: Windows7-64bit
- Java: build 1.8.0_25-b18

Last entry in locator.log: *[info 2015/09/30 17:16:51.703 CEST locator  tid=0x51] Cluster configuration service start up completed successfully and is now running ....*

Last entry in server.log: *[info 2015/09/30 17:21:28.046 CEST server  tid=0x1] CacheServer Configuration:   port=40404 max-connections=800 max-threads=0 notify-by-subscription=true socket-buffer-size=32768 maximum-time-between-pings=60000 maximum-message-count=230000 message-time-to-live=180 eviction-policy=none capacity=1 overflow directory=. groups=[] loadProbe=ConnectionCountProbe loadPollInterval=5000 tcpNoDelay=true*

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're not seeing the same results as described in [Geodein5minutes](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutes) is that you're using three separate windows. Geodein5minutes describes using one single window.

Below shows going through Geodein5minutes with a couple extra commands such as "list members" and "list region" to illustrate.

```
    C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode>.\bin\gfsh.bat
        _________________________     __
       / _____/ ______/ ______/ /____/ /
      / /  __/ /___  /_____  / _____  /
     / /__/ / ____/  _____/ / /    / /
    /______/_/      /______/_/    /_/    v1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT

    Monitor and Manage GemFire
    gfsh>start locator --name=locator
    Starting a GemFire Locator in C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\
    apache-geode\locator...
    ...............................
    Locator in C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\locato
    r on klund-e6420.vmware.com[10334] as locator is currently online.
    Process ID: 1800
    Uptime: 16 seconds
    GemFire Version: 1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
    Java Version: 1.8.0_45
    Log File: C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\locator
    \locator.log
    JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.enable-cluster-configuration=true -Dgemfire.load-cluste
    r-configuration-from-dir=false -Dgemfire.launcher.registerSignalHandlers=true -D
    java.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=9223372036854775806
    Class-Path: C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\lib\g
    emfire-core-1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\bu
    ild\install\apache-geode\lib\gemfire-core-dependencies.jar

    Successfully connected to: [host=klund-e6420.vmware.com, port=1099]

    Cluster configuration service is up and running.

    gfsh>list members
     Name   | Id
    ------- | ------------------------------------------
    locator | klund-e6420(locator:1800:locator):1987

    gfsh>start server --name=server
    Starting a GemFire Server in C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\a
    pache-geode\server...
    .......
    Server in C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\server
    on klund-e6420.vmware.com[40404] as server is currently online.
    Process ID: 5412
    Uptime: 4 seconds
    GemFire Version: 1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT
    Java Version: 1.8.0_45
    Log File: C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\server\
    server.log
    JVM Arguments: -Dgemfire.default.locators=10.118.33.206[10334] -Dgemfire.use-clu
    ster-configuration=true -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=taskkill /F /PID %p -Dgemfire.lau
    ncher.registerSignalHandlers=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.
    gcInterval=9223372036854775806
    Class-Path: C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\build\install\apache-geode\lib\g
    emfire-core-1.0.0-incubating-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\geode\gemfire-assembly\bu
    ild\install\apache-geode\lib\gemfire-core-dependencies.jar

    gfsh>create region --name=region --type=REPLICATE
    Member | Status
    ------ | ------------------------------------
    server | Region "/region" created on "server"

    gfsh>list members
     Name   | Id
    ------- | ------------------------------------------
    locator | klund-e6420(locator:1800:locator):1987
    server  | klund-e6420(server:5412):65511

    gfsh>list regions
    List of regions
    ---------------
    region

    gfsh>
```

After I started the locator, I typed "list members" which shows that GFSH autoconnected to the locator I just started. In the same GFSH window, I then proceed to start the server.

If you want to use separate GFSH windows you can, but you'll need to use the connect command in the other windows.

Comment: I need to use separate windows, because after "start locator --name=locator" I do not get my prompt back. All I see is "Starting a GemFire Locator in ........................................."

Comment: That was a bug that was fixed in GemFire 8.2 and Apache Geode. GFSH consumes the stdout/stderr of the launched process, but calls to BufferedReader.readLine() will block on Windows until the process departs. We changed it to be non-blocking. Try it in GemFire 8.2 or with Geode and you'll see it correctly return to the prompt.

Comment: Was this fixed recently, because I did a git clone of https://github.com/apache/incubator-geode/ last Wednesday ?

Comment: I am using `gfsh>start locator --name=locator1`.. the prompt doesn't come back... I don't see any further movement in the log file either.

Answer (score 1):

When gfsh starts, you have to point it to a running locator using the `connect` command, so that you can create regions etc. The following is an example:

```
gfsh>connect --locator=localhost[10334]
```

Comment: This helps, but now I'm having another issue when creating a region: "No caching members found".

BTW: it might be interesting to add this required step on https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/GEODE/Index#Index-Geodein5minutes

Answer (score 1):

What is the output when you do "list members" in gfsh.
gfsh>connect --locator=localhost[10334]
list members

are the locator and server are in same host?

Comment: "list members": I only see the locator. 
locator and server are indeed running on the same host